# How to observe login state?

Tags: mvvm, singleton, rx-swift

I want View Controllers to be aware of every change in login status. Do I have to make a single tone and subscribe?

Singleton.swift

```
class Singleton {
    static let shared = Singleton()

    let isLogin: BehaviorRelay<Bool>

    private init() {
        isLogin = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)
    }
}
```

SomeViewController

```
class SomeVc: UIViewController {
    Sigleton.shared.isLogin.subscribe(.....)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need a Singleton...

Here's code I use in actual production. This code is in my `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method.

```
_ = UserDefaults.standard.rx.observe(String.self, "token")
    .map { $0 ?? "" }
    .filter { $0.isEmpty }
    .bind(onNext: presentScene(animated: true) { _ in
        LoginViewController.scene { $0.connect() }
    })
```

When the user logs in, I save a token in `UserDefaults`, when the user logs out, I remove it. The above code will present my `LoginViewController` when the user logs out.

If any other view controller needs to track the login state of the user, they can also subscribe to the token observable.

The `presentScene(animated:_:)` function and `scene(_:)` method both come from my [CLE Library](https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools)